# Robovm black bars on top and bottom of 4-inch screens

Tags: java, ios, robovm

I have installed robowm and created the sample app given on the offical website.

It works perfectly on emulator with screen size of 3.5 inch, but black bars occur on top and bottom of screen when I test it with 4 inch emulator or iPhone 5.

Seems like robovm is not supporting 4 inch screen size.
Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RoboVM definitely supports the 4 inch screen. You just have to tell iOS that your app supports the larger screen. The way to do this is to provide a launch screen with the right name and dimensions. Put an image named `Default-568h@2x.png` with dimensions 640x1136 pixels in your `resources/` folder in your RoboVM project and iOS will let your app use the full screen.